# How to write jersey to match "/hello" and "/hello?name=Mike" with different method?

Tags: rest, jersey

The client may request two urls with the same path but different query strings:

```
1. /hello
2. /hello?name=Mike
```

How to use jersey to define two different methods for each of them?

Here is an example:

```
@Path("/hello") 
public class HelloResource {

    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String justHello() {}

    // how to call this method only the query string has "name"
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String helloWithName() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, Jersey only matches the path. See http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html for full details.

You can build your own switch based on the query parameter being present. In general, name=mike is not very RESTy anyways. Jersey does support:

```
 /hello/{name}
```

And that's the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: It's a petty, my program depends on this feature heavily.

Comment: Do you know any other similar library supports this feature?

Comment: Not really, are you sure you don't want to try doing this using REST? It's trendy so support is better.

Comment: Actually, my client will send requests like `PUT /users/1?method=changePwd` or `PUT /users/1?method=changeName`, it use `method=name` for different actions. I don't want to include `actions` in my resource path like `/users/1/changeName` or `/users/1/changePwd`

Comment: I don't know of any framework that works exactly like that. Sadly that's basically exactly what REST is for. /users/{name}/changePwd, /users/{name}/changeName, etc.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I have to use `/users/{name}/{action}`

Comment: Actually, that you can map to different methods with different paths.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can. You just need to have a single method mapped to /hello/ that checks for the query parameter. If it exists, delegate to another method as a sub-resource.

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e374